# Problema na lógica - React não calcula

Tags: javascript, react, lógica

Estou começando com React agora, e tive um exercício pra fazer, o exercício consiste em "sacar" múltiplos de 5 de um caixa eletrônico, porém esqueci de alguma coisa no código, pois quando eu clico em calcular, simplesmente nada acontece.

Segue o código:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './App.css';

export default class Caixa_Eletronico extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            valorSaque: 0,
            n50: 0,
            n20: 0,
            n10: 0,
            n5: 0,
            msg: ''
        }
        this.alterarValor = this.alterarValor.bind(this);
        this.calcular = this.calcular.bind(this);
    }

    alterarValor(event){
        const target = event.target;
        this.setState({
            valorSaque: target.value
        })
    }

    calcular(){
        const dados = this.state;
        let valor = parseInt(dados.valorSaque);

        if(valor % 5 !== 0){
            this.setState({
                msg: 'O valor deve ser múltiplo de 5!'
            });
        } else {
            let n50 = parseInt(valor / 50);
            valor %= 50;

            let n20 = parseInt(valor / 20);
            valor %= 20;

            let n10 = parseInt(valor / 10);
            valor %= 10;

            let n5 = parseInt(valor / 5);

            this.Setstate({
                valorSaque: 0,
                n50: 50,
                n20: 20,
                n10: 10,
                n5: 5,
                msg: ''
        })
    }
}

    render(){
        const {state, props} = this;

        return(
            <div className="borda largura">
                <h2>Caixa Eletrônico</h2>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.alterarValor} placeholder="Deseja sacar quanto?"/>

                    <button type="button" onClick={this.calcular}>Sacar</button>
                </div>

                <div>
                    {state.msg}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <strong>Notas de R$ 50,00: {state.n50} </strong><br/>
                    <strong>Notas de R$ 20,00: {state.n20} </strong><br/>
                    <strong>Notas de R$ 10,00: {state.n10} </strong><br/>
                    <strong>Notas de R$ 5,00: {state.n5} </strong><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Gyraia Sensei, dentro do método `calcular()`, dentro do else, você escreveu `this.Setstate(...` está errado JSX é sensível ao caso o correto é `this.setState(...`

Comment: Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Comment: muito obrigada pela dica e ajuda @AugustoVasques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vários problemas encontrados no seu código, erros de digitação que gerou no `debug` do [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

> Uncaught TypeError: this.Setstate is not a function
> at CaixaEletronico.calcular (:62:22)
> at Object.Vh (react-dom.production.min.js:163)
> at Uh (react-dom.production.min.js:14)
> at Xh (react-dom.production.min.js:14)
> at af (react-dom.production.min.js:14)
> at Yh (react-dom.production.min.js:164)
> at nd (react-dom.production.min.js:15)
> at nc (react-dom.production.min.js:15)
> at Of (react-dom.production.min.js:38)
> at Ac (react-dom.production.min.js:39)

e esse erro diz que o no `Setstate` não é uma função, sim claro não é mesmo o nome correto é `setState`. Outro problema é nome do componente, nunca nome de componente em `React` com `underscore` (`_`) sempre coloque a primeira em maiúsculo e se for nome composto coloque nas iniciais principais em maiúsculo, isso é um padrão utilizado no mundo `React`, e por fim no `setState` que atualiza o números de notas também tinha erro de digitação e pode ser simplificado como eu o fiz, ***exemplo***:

```js
class CaixaEletronico extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            valorSaque: 0,
            n50: 0,
            n20: 0,
            n10: 0,
            n5: 0,
            msg: ''
        }
        this.alterarValor = this.alterarValor.bind(this);
        this.calcular = this.calcular.bind(this);
    }

    alterarValor(event){
        const target = event.target;
        this.setState({
            valorSaque: target.value
        })
    }

    calcular(){        
        let valor = parseInt(this.state.valorSaque);
        if (valor) {
          if(valor % 5 !== 0){
            this.setState({
                msg: 'O valor deve ser múltiplo de 5!'
            });
          } else {
            let n50 = parseInt(valor / 50);
            valor %= 50;

            let n20 = parseInt(valor / 20);
            valor %= 20;

            let n10 = parseInt(valor / 10);
            valor %= 10;

            let n5 = parseInt(valor / 5);

            this.setState({                
                n50,
                n20,
                n10,
                n5,
                msg: ''
          })
      }
   }
}

    render(){
        const {state, props} = this;
        return(
            <div className="borda largura">
                <h2>Caixa Eletrônico</h2>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.alterarValor} placeholder="Deseja sacar quanto?"/>
                    <button type="button" onClick={this.calcular}>Sacar</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {state.msg}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <strong>Notas de R$ 50,00: {state.n50} </strong><br/>
                    <strong>Notas de R$ 20,00: {state.n20} </strong><br/>
                    <strong>Notas de R$ 10,00: {state.n10} </strong><br/>
                    <strong>Notas de R$ 5,00: {state.n5} </strong><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<CaixaEletronico/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Utilize sempre o `debug`, esse vai ajudar a verificar erros no seu código, pressione a tecla <kbd>F12</kbd> do navegador e na guia `console` verifique se aconteceu algum erro.

Comment: Deu certinho amigo @Virgilio Novic.

Obrigada pela ajuda!